# How to update an user with JavaScript on Django

Tags: javascript, django, oracle

hope someone can help me with this as I´m starting to go crazy not finding anything.

I need to make an update for a certain user using django and oracle, me and my team decided to use javascript for the update but we can´t figure it out.

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}

{% block titulo %}
<title>Registro_coach</title>
{% endblock %}

{% load static %}

{% block css %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'core/css/estilo_r_coach.css' %}">
{% endblock %}

{% block contenido %}
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h3>Coachs registrados</h3>
    <table id="tablaCoach" class="table table-bordered table-dark">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Run</th>
          <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
          <th scope="col">Apellido Paterno</th>
          <th scope="col">Apellido Materno</th>
          <th scope="col">Correo</th>
          <th scope="col">Telefono</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for i in coachs%}
          <tr>
            <td>{{i.0}}</td>
            <td>{{i.1}}</td>
            <td>{{i.2}}</td>
            <td>{{i.3}}</td>
            <td>{{i.5}}</td>
            <td>{{i.4}}</td>
            <th><input type="button" class="btnModificar" value="Modificar"></th>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5 ml-auto">
    <h3>Registro Coach</h3>
    <form id="FormCoach" action="" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %} 
      <input class="controls" type="text" name="run" id="run" placeholder="Run" oninput="checkRut(this)" maxlength="10" required>
      <input class="controls" type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Ingrese su Nombre" required>
      <input class="controls" type="text" name="a_paterno" id="a_paterno" placeholder="Apellido paterno" required>
      <input class="controls" type="text" name="a_materno" id="a_materno" placeholder="Apellido materno" required>
      <input class="controls" type="email" name="correo" id="correo" placeholder="Ingrese su correo" required>
      <input class="controls" type="text" name="telefono" id="telefono" placeholder="telefono" required>
  
      <input class="botons" type="submit" value="Agregar" onclick="limpiarFormulario()" >
      <input class="botons" type="submit" value="Modificar" >
    </form>
    {{mensaje}}
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

We use that whole code to make a form that is used on the insert process that is done on the views

now, our try on making the update is this

```
{% block js%}
<script src=" static/core/js/validacion.js"></script>
<script>
  function limpiarFormulario(){
    document.getElementById("FormCoach").reset();
  };
</script>

<script>
  $(".btnModificar").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').each(function(){
      var textval = $(this).text();
      
      $("#run").val(textval).readOnly;
      $("#nombre").val(textval);
      $("#a_paterno").val(textval);
      $("#a_pmaterno").val(textval);
      $("#correo").val(textval);
      $("#telefono").val(textval);
    });
  });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

it is supossed to get the data that is show on a table inside the form (which contains the users added) and with a button send all that data again to the form for its update, we succeded on sending the data to the form but we still can't get it to update.

I've tried everything on my knowledge but I really can´t figure out a way on how to do it, please, if anyone know, even if it is done on another way I would be really grateful.

Edit: view, it is on spanish tho

```
def registro_coach(request):
    p_coach = 'SP_LISTA_COACH'
    data ={
        'coachs' : listar(p_coach)
    }

    if request.POST:
        run = request.POST.get('run')
        nombre = request.POST.get('nombre')
        ap_paterno = request.POST.get('a_paterno')
        ap_materno = request.POST.get('a_materno')
        telefono = request.POST.get('telefono')
        correo = request.POST.get('correo')
        contrasena = run[:4]
        contrato = '1'
        salida = agregar_coach(run,nombre,ap_paterno,ap_materno,telefono,correo,contrasena,contrato)
        if salida == 1:
            data['mensaje'] = 'agregado correctamente'
            data['coachs'] = listar(p_coach)
        else:
            data['mensaje'] = 'no se ha podido agregar'

    return render(request, 'core/registro_coach.html', data)

def mofificar_coach():
    pass
```

Comment: In django, views are called by visiting a url. These are defined in urls.py in the appropriate app. When you resubmit to the same url, you will have to check for the http method to decide what to do next. For the record, this is not how forms are usually created and consumed with django. This might help: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/django/django_form_processing.htm

Comment: Can you show your `views.py` file ? Where you preform the code to update a record

Comment: yeah, can show that, tho, we don't have the update yet only the insert, what we want to do is to make the update on the insert together like fused, like if the user is already on the db then update him, if not insert him, gonna upload the view on the post

Comment: Read up on the Oracle [MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/MERGE.html#GUID-5692CCB7-24D9-4C0E-81A7-A22436DC968F) statement which may be useful, possibly with a SELECT FROM TABLE()